# How to stop/aboard threads if timeout in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

I am working on a code which will create a series threads (e.g: `Function GetMACAddress(IPAddr as string) as string`). Each thread job will take different execution time to process (will take way longer if IP not occupied by any PC & no valid MAC Address will be return at the end).

How can I manage & monitor each thread in such a way so that I can stop/abort at anytime if it still yet to be completed after a specified timeout period (say Timeout = 100ms)? In my case I'll need to scan from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255

What sort of threading coding architecture I should using here?

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code

```
Imports System

Public Class TimedThread

    Dim WithEvents Timer1 As Timers.Timer
    Dim Thread1 As Threading.Thread

    Dim Timeout1 As Integer

    Sub New(ByVal Timeout1 As Integer, ByVal ThreadStart1 As Threading.ThreadStart)
        Me.Timeout1 = Timeout1

        If Timeout1 > 0 Then
            Timer1 = New Timers.Timer(Timeout1)
        End If

        Thread1 = New Threading.Thread(ThreadStart1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Start()
        If Not Thread1 Is Nothing Then
            Thread1.Start()
        End If

        If Timeout1 > 0 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Elapsed() Handles Timer1.Elapsed
        If Thread1.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Running Then
            Thread1.Abort()
            Timer1.Enabled = False

            'Remove this line after testing
            MsgBox("Thread aborted")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose()
        If Not Timer1 Is Nothing Then
            If Thread1.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Running Then
                Thread1.Abort()
            End If

            Timer1.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

to test the code, add these lines inside your form

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Timeout1 As Integer = 1000
    Dim TimedThread1 As New TimedThread(Timeout1, AddressOf TestSub)

    TimedThread1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TestSub()
    Dim i, a As Integer

    For i = 0 To 1000000000
        a += 1
    Next

    MsgBox("Operation complete")
End Sub
```

This demonstration is for a single thread. If you want to use multiple threads, use an array of the TimedThread Class.

To set for example an IP address as a input parameter and get the MAC address as a return value, you can use the following approach.

```
Public Structure NetInfo
    Dim IP_Address As String
    Dim MAC_Address As String

    Sub New(ByVal IP_Address As String, ByVal MAC_Address As String)
        Me.IP_Address = IP_Address
        Me.MAC_Address = MAC_Address
    End Sub
End Structure

Private Event ReturnValues(ByVal ReturnInfo1 As NetInfo)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Timeout1 As Integer = 0
    Dim TimedThread1 As New TimedThread(Timeout1, Sub() GetMacAddress("192.168.0.1"))

    TimedThread1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub GetMacAddress(ByVal IP_Address1 As String)
    'Processes for getting the MAC address based on the IP address.
    '
    '
    Dim MAC_Address1 As String = "Test return value"
    Dim ReturnInfo1 As New NetInfo(IP_Address1, MAC_Address1)

    RaiseEvent ReturnValues(ReturnInfo1)
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadReturnValues(ByVal ReturnInfo1 As NetInfo) Handles Me.ReturnValues
    MsgBox("IP = " & ReturnInfo1.IP_Address & " MAC = " & ReturnInfo1.MAC_Address)
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I set input parameter and get the return value of the thread? for example input is "IP_Address", thread return "MAC_Address"